# How to install bimp for gimp 2.8 on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, gimp

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgimp2.0-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-dev (>= 2.12.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It says broken packages, I am not a techy so do not understand the jargons 
"You must install `libgimp2.0-dev` and `libpcre3-dev` packages in order to have 
the full set of libraries and dependences to compile BIMP (names can differ depending on the distro)."

in the installation document
I have searched for all answers possible given online, but none has been able to resolve my issue of installing bimp

If you could advice the possible steps to install bimp would be of help

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Enter these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Try to fix the broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And enter again `sudo apt-get -f install`.

This should solve your dependency problems and you can now install `libgimp2.0-dev` again.

- Next solution is to run:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
  ```

  If it shows any held packages, it is best to eliminate them. Packages are held because of dependency conflicts that `apt` cannot resolve. Try this command to find and repair the conflicts:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
  ```

  If it cannot fix the conflicts, it will exit with:

  `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.`

  Delete the held packages one by one, running `dist-upgrade` each time, until there are no more held packages. Then reinstall any needed packages. Be sure to use the `--dry-run` option, so that you are fully informed of consequences:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --dry-run package-name
  ```

  Since removing the package you are trying to install may not be ideal, you might also try finding a repository that has the packages you need to satisfy the dependencies.

Finally, if all else fails, you can attempt to satisfy the dependencies yourself, either by finding and installing the necessary packages, or by installing them from source and then creating “[deb][2]” packages for them.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa/142808#142808)

Comment: There are no broken packages.

Comment: Well as you said i have again run into unmet dependencies

Comment: following is the process that i did as per your recommendation

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxext-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxinerama-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxi-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Depends: libxrandr-dev (>= 2:1.2.99) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxfixes-dev (>= 1:3.0.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxcomposite-dev (>= 1:0.2.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxdamage-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-3) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Recommends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
vaanie@vaanie-Aspire-5742:~/Downloads/gimp-plugin-bimp-1.15$ so what do i need to do next?

Comment: @VaaniePanesar See edit - I made a mistake...

Comment: @VaaniePanesar I have made another edit, with another option. You can try this. If that still doesn't work, then check out the link at the bottom of the answer, marked `Source`

Comment: Finally problem resolved, actually my mistake i realized that  when i went to the source changed the settings as recommended on my software & updates post which i followed all the steps till "sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade" once all the broken packages were fixed then I opened the bimp plugin folder "in terminal" and "sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev" this time it was installed easily also when i tried to install "libpcre3-dev " however it had already gotten installed, finally i just copied the "bimp locale" folder into the gimp 2.8 plugin folder.